# CSS Transition effect on my itty bitty arrow

Tags: css, css-transitions, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pCeGu/

See JsFiddle above.  Note the itty bitty arrow that pops under the buttons. Is it possible to make that thing fade in/out with the other elements?

Answer (score 2):

Per this question: [CSS :after hover Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306765/css-after-hover-transition)

Apparently Firefox 4 is the only browser that currently supports the transitioning of pseudo elements:(

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a unicode graphical character with some absolute positioning as part of your link, instead of using `:after`.

See: [What characters can be used for up/down triangle (arrow without stem) for display in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701192/ascii-character-for-up-down-triangle-arrow-to-display-in-html)

Comment: any idea how to pass unicode into the content attribute of the after pseudo element?

Comment: You have to use an escaped reference to the unicode value: http://alanhogan.com/tips/css/special-characters-in-generated-content but I think you'll run into the same problem that you cannot transition pseudo elements if you put it in ::after. I think Diodeus is suggesting you put a unicode character in your markup.

Comment: That is what I am suggesting. Put an absolutely-positioned element containing the unicode character inside your current element.